# How to call 2 functions on onclick in coffee script

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to call 2 functions on click one button in coffeescript.but i am getting error `dialtone() is not a function`

```
dialtone1 = ->
  audio = document.getElementById('dialtone1')
  if audio.paused
    audio.play()
  else
    audio.currentTime = 0
  return
alex.on Events.Click, (event, layer) -> timer() dialtone()
```

How can i solve this

Comment: Is there a separate dialtone function? dialtone1 is defined in your sample code

Answer (score 1):

You have two things wrong:

1. There is no `dialtone` function, the function is called `dialtone1`.
2. `timer() dialtone()` doesn't do what you think it does.

When CoffeeScript sees `timer() dialtone()`, it thinks you mean

```
timer()(dialtone())
```

i.e. call what `timer` returns as a function with what `dialtone` returns as its argument.

Fix the typo in the function name (either where you define it or where you call it) and use two statements to call the functions:

```
alex.on Events.Click, (event, layer) -> timer(); dialtone()
# ---------------------------------------------^
```

or

```
alex.on Events.Click, (event, layer) ->
  timer()
  dialtone()
```

or even:

```
timer_and_dialtone = ->
  timer()
  dialtone()
alex.on Events.Click, timer_and_dialtone
```